# Mathematica 12.0.0 crashes on second 'Quit[]'

Tags: front-end, version-12

I am trying to develop a module, and run 'Quit[]' from within a cell in a notebook to clear all symbols before reloading the module that I have modified.  The second time I do this after starting Mathematica, it becomes unresponsive, and I need to use Windows to kill Mathematica.  I had similar problems with 11.3, but it seems to have become "reliably unreliable" (and intensely frustrating) since the upgrade.  Any suggestions on how to iterate through attempts without this issue?

Comment: To clear all variables in the `Global` context use `Clear["Global\`*"]`; `Clear["context\`*"]` clears all symbols in a particular context. Use `ClearAll`if you want to clear attributes, messages, or defaults associated with symbols.

Comment: What are the details of your module, how is it loaded, etc...? I think that's a critical detail here.

Comment: It is a small package, loaded using Get["tensora'", Path -> "<absolute path>"].  I've grown distrustful of the Clear["tensora'*"] approach, since behaviour has suggested that not all symbols were cleared (and inherently, one has to understand exactly which namespaces have been created).  So I have taken to Quit[] in response: nothing like debugging with a ghost symbol definition confusing things.  And if Quit[] can't be relied on, what is to be trusted about Mathematica?  (Note: grave replaced with apostrophe here)

Comment: `Quit[]` is a perfectly valid way to clear symbols; as you say it's the only really reliable way to get a clean slate.  If `Quit[]` is causing a hang in your front end then I think you may need to contact customer support.

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but I had issues recently with that syntax of `Get`, where I was using the option `Path -> <folder name>` but the way you are supposed to use that option is `Path -> {<folder name>}`.  It didn't cause a crash, but did have issues getting the file.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue using only the command line interface (i.e. WolframKernel)?

Comment: Okay, it sounds like this is not widespread problem.  So the suggestion of customer support seems like a good idea.  (On the Path->{"..."} syntax, I don't see it documented. Oddly, it seems to make a difference: 'Quit[]' several times without an issue!)

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I might be seeing something similar: when I close the last window of Mathematica, it crashes my X window system. I'm running 12.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @BosonBear, no, since I chose not to continue subscribing (I am very disenchanted by Wolfram's dismal focus on the underlying robustness and correctness of Mathematica), I did not move past 12.0.0.  I'm starting to wonder whether there isn't a difference in behaviour between networked licence and laptop licence; I suspect the latter is more prone to this behaviour.

Comment: np. I've realized my crash is caused by Mathemtica trying to display the home window when I close my last notebook. It's fixed by opting to ``quit mathematica when the last window is closed.''